# How do you count specific rows with PDO within a function?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I see other tutorials on counting rows, but  none on counting specific rows `$row[scope]` for specific results.  How can this be done?

```
function counting(){
$query = "SELECT    * 
          FROM      table";

$result->fetchAll($sql, $params);   
$num_rows = count($result);

$counter = 0;

    //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ //old code
    foreach($result as $row){
        if($row[scope] == "all"){
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    $return = ($counter > 0)?TRUE:FALSE;
}

protected function fetchAll($sql, $params)
{
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchALL(DatabaseAdapter::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: Hey, why don't you use the SQL language to do that for you? It's quite the right tool for the job in this case. (e.g) `SELECT * FROM table where scope = 'all';` -- At that point you won't need PHP to filter it

Comment: This is just a piece of a long formula of about 5 different rows in the function (even though I made it simple), so I wanted to know the basics.

Comment: The basics are to let sql do it 100x quicker. Like `select count(*) as theCount from myTable where scope='all'`

Comment: Is there no way to count with foreach?

Comment: Sure, if you want to drag your system to a halt and not learn sql :p

Comment: ok, I can integrate the MySQL into it.  Sounds like a plan....  upgrading While loops can be a pain sometimes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two functions for that.

Instead of `fetchAll()` you need just a general purpose function to run a query that returns *PDOStatement* which is essential.

```
protected function sql($sql, $params)
{
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}
```

in most cases it will work exactly the same way as your fetchAll() function *without any changes in the code*, but in case you explicitly need to get an array from it, you can always attach a fetchAll() to its call:

```
$result = $this->sql($sql, $params)->fetchAll();
```

And the second function you need is for the actual count:

```
function counting($value)
{
    $query = "SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE scope = ?";
    return $this->sql($sql, [$value])->fetchColumn();
}
```

using such a function you can count (or detect the existence) for any scope.

Note that thanks to returned PDOStatement we are able to get another type of result - a scalar value instead of array.

> upgrading While loops can be a pain sometimes....

You see, when SQL and PDO are *properly used*, you scarcely need a while loop at all

Comment: So you have to hit the database twice.  This helped clarify this.  Please fix fethColumn for other users when they see this. :)

Comment: sorry, why twice?

Comment: Sorry, I was using this logic for a function of counting within another function that I didn't add to the question itself.  You are correct with your logic!